# An internal error occurred during: "JDI Event Dispatch" java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: debugging, events, dispatch, jdi

I have my java applet codee,I am trying to debug using eclipse Indigo EE. I am trying to debug on remote using
debug configuration and port. 
When I try to execute the application, it gives always an error message,

An internal error occurred during: "JDI Event Dispatch" java.lang.NullPointerException.

and control is not stopping in the break point.

Please help.

Regards,
KSAT

Answer (score 1):

Try increasing the debugger timeout (under Preferences -> Java -> Debug).

Answer (score 0):

It was because one of objects was not created. In my case it was service, to which I wanted to bind, but it was null.

Answer (score 0):

Terminate and relaunch. It worked for me.